# Do immigration officer take biometric at airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas

I wanna know do immigration officers asking for biometrics at frankfurt airport (Germany).

Comment: Why would they not match? Are you using someone else's passport/visa?

Comment: Of course not my visa has my picture, just have a concern as sometimes in past my local documents, not passport fingerprint did not work

Comment: Immigration officers will try to verify that the visa and passport are genuine, and that you are the person described in both. So "take" is not quite the right word, "match" describes it better.

Answer (score 6):

If you are worried about fingerprint not reading correctly, its shouldn't be an issue. If its not read properly, it will be reattempted after cleaning your hand. If still not working, usually, they will match up with the rest of the details like your photo and all.

You won't be denied entry just because your fingerprint is not reading properly.

Comment: Do immigration officers in fact take fingerprints in the Schengen area?

Comment: @phoog I am not sure. This is meant as a general answer.

Comment: @phoog I think it is only upon request for now. EES is supposed to ask for biometrics if/when it finally comes into effect.

Comment: Yes, when the EES is activ, the Biometric data (fingerprints and facial image) will be taken from third country nationals exempt from the visa obligation, where this hasn't yet been done. For visa holders this has allready been done. Upon entry, should the verification of the facial image fail, the verification shall be carried out using fingerprints and vice versa. The same thing happens in the US for first time ESTA travellers and for me it was very fast and uncomplicated.

Comment: @phoog I was asked to provide fingerprint when I applied for Shengen visa today.

Comment: @AnishSheela but will your fingerprints be checked when you use the visa to enter the Schengen area?

Comment: @phoog Will let you know in one month. :)

Comment: @AnishSheela That is normal. Fingerprints will only be checked if the verification of the facial image fails.

Answer (score 2):

Automated gates (which [in Frankfurt](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/transferring-at-fra/passport-and-id-checks.html) are only open to EU and Swiss citizens and, with prior enrollment, to citizens of a handful of other countries) do rely on biometric data, namely the picture of your face that's recorded in your passport.

Fingerprints are not scanned as a matter of course when entering the Schengen area. There is also no requirement to do so and no process to record or store them.

If you have a short-stay visa, your picture and fingerprints have been added to the Visa Information System (VIS) when you applied. Other law enforcement databases, including the Schengen Information System (SIS) also include biometric data. So if there are doubts whether the passport and visa you present are really yours or any reason to suspect that there could be an alert about you, border guards can use these databases to further ascertain your identity.